# If $f''(x)$ exist in $(a, b)$ then there exist $\xi \in (a, b)$ so that $f''(\xi)(b-a)=f'(b)-f'(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable on $[a, b]$ and $f'$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$. How can we prove that there exists $\xi \in (a, b)$, such that $f'(b)-f'(a)=f''(\xi)(b-a)$ ?

We cannot use the mean value theorem because $f'(x)$ may have discontinuities at $a$ or $b$.

I came up with this: If $f''(\xi_1)>\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$ and $f''(\xi_2)<\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$ for some $\xi_1, \xi_2$, then by Darboux's theorem there will be $\xi$, such that $f''(\xi)=\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$. Therefore we can assume $f''(x)>\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$ or $f''(x)<\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$ for all $x$.

Am I going the right direction?

Comment: Isn't this just the average value theorem applied to second derivatives?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, average value theorem? I never heard that term before, where is it used? I believe the term Mean Value theroem is used more commonly.

Comment: What's your definition of differentiable on $[a,b]$? I've seen it expressed in nonequivalent ways. The more general version is that $f$ can be extended to a differentiable function on some open $U$ containing $[a,b]$. But some others instead call it this if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-} f'(x)$ exist. If your definition is the latter case, then it is just the mean value theorem.

Comment: @Robert, to use Darboux's theorem we need $f$ to be differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}, f'(b)=\lim_{x\to b-}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$ to exist, which is differentiability at any point of $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing $f$ with the function $g(x)=f(x)+cx^2$ for appropriately chosen $c$, we may assume that $f'(a)=f'(b)$ (adding $cx^2$ to $f(x)$ does not change whether the equation $f'(b)-f'(a)=f''(\xi)(b-a)$ is true since it just adds $2c(b-a)$ to both sides).  So, assuming $f'(a)=f'(b)$, we want to show there exists $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $f''(\xi)=0$. [This step is similar to how you reduce the mean value theorem to Rolle's theorem by adding a linear function.]

As you have said, using Darboux's theorem, we may assume that either $f''(x)>0$ or $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$; let's say $f''(x)>0$ (the other case is similar).  This means $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.  But together with $f'(a)=f'(b)$, this violates Darboux's theorem: picking any $d\in (a,b)$, suppose $f'(d)>f'(a)$.  Then $f'(d)>f'(b)$ so by Darboux there exists $e\in (d,b)$ such that $f'(d)>f'(e)>f'(b)$, contradicting that $f'$ is increasing on $(a,b)$.  Similarly, if $f'(d)<f'(a)$, there is $e\in (a,d)$ such that $f'(a)>f'(e)>f'(d)$ which is again a contradiction.  So we must have $f'(d)=f'(a)$ for all $d\in (a,b)$, but that again contradicts the fact that $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.