# Mean value theorem for second derivative, Zorich

Tags: calculus, mean-value-theorem

I have the following problem (Zorich 5.3.7(b)): let $f \in C(I)$, $f$ have derivative on $I$ (so $f'$ exists on $I$, but might be discontinuous in general) $[a, b] \subset I$ and $f \in C^{(2)}((a, b))$. Prove that $\exists \xi \in (a, b)$, such that $f'(b) - f'(a) = f''(\xi) \cdot (b - a)$

I cant use mean value theorem here, because for mean value theorem we need $f'$ be continuous at $[a, b]$, but since it has second derivative only in $(a, b)$, than $f'$ must be continuous only at $(a, b)$ and might be discontinuous at corner points

I tried to rewrite proof of mean value theorem for $g(x) = f'(x) - \frac{f'(b) - f'(a)}{b - a} \cdot (x - a)$, but havent succed here. I can say that $g$ is also continuous on $(a, b)$, but I cant say that it reach it maximum, and minimum (I need that to find point $\xi$ s.t. $g'(\xi) = 0$)

I guess this statement should be corollary of Darboux's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis) ), but cant figure out how to obtain initial statement from Darboux's theorem. I can say that $f'$ continuous at point $a$ or $\exists \epsilon$ s.t. $f'(a) \in [f'(a + \epsilon), f'(b)]$ and if we get first scenraio everything good, we can use MeanValue, but if we in second case I cant obtain initial statement

Comment: Doesn't $f \in C^{(1)}(I)$ mean that $f$ has a continuous derivative in $I$ ?

Comment: @MartinR in this case I mean $f$ just have derivative on $I$, so the derivative itself might be discontinuous, I will fix initial statement, thank you

Comment: Yeah, its exactly my problem, thank you!

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2679630/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%27(b)%20-%20f%27(a)%20%3D%20f%27%27(%5Cxi)%20%5Ccdot%20(b%20-%20a)%24)